# Why parameters in stack isn't continuous

Tags: c, assembly, x86, variadic-functions, calling-convention

I'm trying to create an os for learning. To format string, I create `sprintf` like below:

```cpp
void sprintf(char *buf, const char *format, ...) {
    ...
}
```

I don't use the `__builtin_va_list` but manually get the address of `format`. By adding 4 byte per param it does get the correct extra params.
But when I reconstruct it to `vsprintf` and try to use it in other functions it fails.

```cpp
void vsprintf(char *buf, const char *format, void *args) {
    ...
}
...
void vga_printf(int16_t left, int16_t top, const char *format, uint8_t color, uint8_t back, ...) {
    static char buffer[256];
    vsprintf(buffer, format, &back);
    // kPrintf("%xd %xd %xd %xd %xd\n", &left, &top, &format, &color, &back);
    vga_putstr(left, top, buffer, color, back);
}
```

```
 4de:   8d 45 e8                lea    -0x18(%ebp),%eax
 4e1:   50                      push   %eax
 4e2:   8d 45 ec                lea    -0x14(%ebp),%eax
 4e5:   50                      push   %eax
 4e6:   8d 45 10                lea    0x10(%ebp),%eax
 4e9:   50                      push   %eax
 4ea:   8d 45 f0                lea    -0x10(%ebp),%eax
 4ed:   50                      push   %eax
 4ee:   8d 45 f4                lea    -0xc(%ebp),%eax
 4f1:   50                      push   %eax
```

The `vsprintf` cannot get the correct extra params.

After printing the addresses like above (the `kPrintf`) and checking the assembly (showed above, the code section that push param for `kPrintf`), I notice that `format` have address `16(%ebp)`, while it should be (`-16(%ebp)`) in my view. Meanwhile, the address of `color` is `-16(%ebp)`.
I don't know if it has sth. to do with my problem.

I think there must be sth. wrong with my `vsprintf`. How can I correctly implement that?

---

I think I've said what that assembly is.

> showed above, the code section that push param for `kPrintf`

It is the code that outer function push the param to stack for calling it.

---

As the vsprintf isn't short, I put it on [ubuntu paste](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/2YVcyydbmm/).
Notice that I don't follow the standard syntax. I just want to implement an usable one. Please don't blame my problem.

---

After changing to gcc's __builtin_va_list, it works.

Thanks for all suggestions.

Comment: Please show a [mcve]

Comment: You are creating an OS and asking _us_ how the stack frames and ABI for that OS works? What are you actually doing here?

Comment: Are you _actually_ creating an OS or are you just reimplementing `vsprintf`? And what exactly is this snippet of assembly code? Please [edit] and  add some context information.

Comment: What C statement is that asm from?  The commented out `kPrintf`?  Presumably GCC copies some of the stack args from their incoming slots to local var slots below the return address, like it sometimes does.  But not the pointer-to-const char `format` for some reason.  IDK what that has to do with a va_list, though.  Oh, you're trying to pass the address of one of the named args to `vsprintf`, as the va_list?  Yeah that'll break if GCC chooses to copy an arg.

Comment: You're supposed to use va_list which knows where to get the parameters.

Comment: I am creating an OS. It's my fault that I've forgot to mention the ABI. The compiler target is i686-elf, and I use qemu-system-i386 to emulate it.

Comment: I don't know how can I show you the minimal reproducible example. Maybe I push my source to github? I even don't know if it only happens on x86 or on x86_64 too.

Comment: Yes, if I cannot solve it I will use the __builtin_va_list instead of reimplementing va_list. I'm just trying to know why I cannot do that.

Comment: Stack args *are* contiguous.  I think your problem is that `&back` can be a copy of the stack arg, not the address of its original incoming location.  That's a separate assumption which GCC will sometimes violate (IDK why).  At least that's what I think is probably going wrong; I don't think your question very clearly describes things, but I think your code depends on that assumption.

Comment: Thanks. Then I should use the built in va_list provided by gcc.

Comment: @liaohy `__builtin_va_list` exists because there is no way to implement this yourself in a reliable manner.  Manually doing pointer arithmetic on argument pointers is undefined behaviour and the compiler will punish you for trying that.

Comment: You don't even have to use the `__builtin` version, just `#include <stdarg.h>` and use `va_list` like any normal program would.  It is part of  a freestanding implementation, so it doesn't make OS calls or anything like that, and it can safely be used in OS or bare-metal code.